# How to list all JMS providers including Default MQ messaging provider with particular scope

Tags: jms, websphere, ibm-mq, jython, websphere-7

I have a wsadmin command to get list of JMS providers for all scope level

`AdminJMS.listJMSProviders()`

The above code is going to have the below output

```
['"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider(cells/redhatserverNode01Cell/nodes/redhatserverNode01/servers/server1|resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider)"', 
'"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider(cells/redhatserverNode01Cell/nodes/redhatserverNode01|resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider)"', 
'"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider(cells/redhatserverNode01Cell|resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider)"', 
'sample(cells/redhatserverNode01Cell/nodes/redhatserverNode01/servers/server1|resources.xml#JMSProvider_1487316020150)']
```

what my question is

1. How to get JMS providers for particular scope
2. The above output displays all provider except default MQ messaging provider, how to get **Default MQ messaging provider as well**

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with displaying the default JMS provider, but you can use AdminConfig.list to filter by scope,

```
wsadmin>print AdminConfig.list('JMSProvider', '*cells/myCell/nodes/myNode/servers/server1*')
"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider(cells/myCell/nodes/myNode/servers/server1|resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider)"

wsadmin>print AdminConfig.list('JMSProvider', '*cells/myCell/nodes/myNode|*')
"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider(cells/myCell/nodes/myNode|resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider)"

wsadmin>print AdminConfig.list('JMSProvider', '*cells/myCell|*')
"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider(cells/myCell|resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider)"
```

Comment: it n't working for me...i won't getng providers correctly

Comment: Are you seeing an error or incorrect result?  I should also give an example that clarifies that for cell and node scope, you should be including the | character before the wildcard to avoid unwanted matches. I'll add that to the answer above.